# How to review a previous version of an answer?

Tags: support

So I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317464/641833) and someone else edited it.  When I checked my answer today I noticed that it was missing some words and wanted to see if they were in my original version.

When I open the edit link in a new tab I can see the dropdown with the different versions, but changing what is selected does not load that version.

What is the correct way to view the previous version of my answer?

Comment: click on the `edited Feb 14 '14 at 17:25` link.  he only added 2 chars

Answer (score 4):

You can view a post's previous revisions by clicking on the time stamp of the edit.

[image: Image of Edit Link]

If you click on this link, it will bring you to the post's [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13317464/revisions).

In this case, it shows that revision 2 made these changes

[image: Revision 2]

The editor added two backticks (`` ` ``) around your angle bracketed ( `<` / `>` ) word because it was initially seen as an HTML tag and not rendered in the post.